# ScrollView overlay during video playback

Tags: android, video, overlay

**Is it possible to have an overlay pop up upon tapping the screen, during fullscreen video playback? This overlay would contain a ScrollView of Images and respective Text labels.**

Imagine if you will, a movie streaming in fullscreen. Upon tapping the screen, a scrollable overlay would appear across the bottom with a photo and name of all actors in that particular scene. Hope the example helped.

From what I've managed to find, the 'RelativeLayout' could provide the answer I need. Almost all the questions I found relating to this, concerned either overlays on Maps or Camera feed, not streaming video.

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

will keep diggin'...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step #1: Create a `RelativeLayout`

Step #2: Put the `VideoView` or `SurfaceView` in the `RelativeLayout`

Step #3: Put the `ScrollView` in the `RelativeLayout` as a later child than the `VideoView`/`SurfaceView` (e.g., later in the XML)

Step #4: Make the `ScrollView` be gone (`android:visibility="gone"`)

Step #5: On a touch event on the `VideoView`/`SurfaceView`, make the `ScrollView` be visible using `setVisibility()`

Step #6: Have some way to dismiss the `ScrollView` (e.g., BACK button), returning it to its normal "gone" state

Comment: Many thanks CommonsWare! Super fast  and broken down answer. You mention "VideoView" as apposed to "MediaPlayer". Part of my confusion was not correctly understanding the difference between the two. I was thinking along the lines of MP, where as VideoView provides exactly what I need.

Comment: @Michael: You don't get *quite* as much control with `VideoView` than  you do with the `MediaPlayer`/`SurfaceView` combo, but if `VideoView` fits your needs, it's certainly simple enough to use.